# Javascript arrays subtract a value from every element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code written and I have no idea why it is not working. Essentially, I am trying to subtract 255 from every value in an array, but it **must** be ordered where 255 is first (I can't just do i - 255, it won't get me the values I need). I have also tried i+-255 to no avail.

```
function makeReverse(original, output){
  for (i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
    output[i]=original[i]; //copy original array to output array
    if ((i % 4) !== 3) {
      output[i] = output[255 - i]; //why this is not working is beyond me the 
                                     values keep reading 0 for rgb
    }
  }
  console.log(output);
  return output;
}
```

Comment: please add some examples.

Comment: You're not subtracting from the value, but from the index.

Comment: is `i`defined? Should be `var i = 0`

Comment: What do you mean by "*it MUST be ordered where 255 is first*"? Please show us an example `original` array and the expected value of `output` after calling the function.

Comment: Just saying, `i - 255` is exactly the same as `i + -255`.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Please show an example.

Comment: I found a way to get the code to work the solution to achieve the results I want is to do:
'output[i] = 255 - output[i];'

Comment: I meant I needed to have 255 minus the value in the array (for each array). I was inverting the rgb (but not alpha) values of a bitmapped image.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be using `map`. Something like this:

```
original.map(function(element){
   return element - 255;
});
```

Or in ES6:

```
original.map(element => element - 255);
```

Or if you only want to subtract from the value under a condition:

```
original.map(function(value){
   if(value % 4 !== 3){
       return value - 255;
   } else {
       return value;
   }
});
```

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to find out how `map` works.

Comment: I would call that variable `index`, not `element` (if indeed we are reordering the elements instead of subtracting 255 from each element).

Answer (score 0):

why you subtracting from index [i-255] . 
subtract it from value like this

```
output[i] = output[i]-255;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
output[i] = original[255 - i];
```

This would make your output array the reverse-order of the original array (for elements whose index is not 3 mod 4).